# User changed by cloud function when queried from client side returns stale data

Tags: javascript, parse-server

I am having the logged in user make some changes on itself. These changes happen in the cloud function called by the client code. The cloud code executes correctly and returns back after which I query the user table to get the updated data but it gives back old data and the updated fields are missing. Using the latest available parse-latest.js from CDN.

I have already tried sending the users session token in the save call and also the useMasterKey but no change in behaviour.

Steps to reproduce

1. Call a cloud function that changes a field for the currently logged in User
2. Once cloud function has completed and returned to client side query the user table to get latest data.
3. If you check this data is stale data and does not include the latest data.

Here is the sample code
This is the call to the cloud function which is inside a promise.

```
Parse.Cloud.run("notification_update", params))
    .then(function(obj) {
        dfd.resolve(obj);
    }, function onError(err) {
        console.error(err)
        dfd.reject(err);
}
```

The relevant code in cloud function

```
currentUser.set("team", team);
console.log("Session token ");
console.log(currentUser.getSessionToken());
promises.push(currentUser.save(null, { sessionToken: currentUser.getSessionToken() }));
```

Once the cloud function returns I call this function. I check in the parse DB the data is updated.

```
var refresh = function onRefresh(dfd) {
      console.debug("Refresh user was triggered..");
     var currentUser = Parse.User.current();
     var q = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
     q.include("team");
     q.get(currentUser.id)
        .then(function success(user) {
        currentUser.set({
            team: user.get("team"),           //Here the data is not updated
        });
        if (dfd && dfd.resolve) {
            dfd.resolve(currentUser);
        }
    }, function onError(error) {
        if (dfd && dfd.reject) {
            dfd.reject(error);
        }
    });
}
```

Additionally when I check the response from the server in my Network tab in Chrome, I see that the user has all the updated data.

[image: Here you can the response has returned updated data and the team object is updated]

[image: In this image you see while debugging the response you can see the team is undefined]

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just do a query against the user (me) instead of running a full pledged query to fetch the user.

```
Parse.User.become(sessionToken).then(function(user){
    //User Object is available to you here
})
```

Comment: Interesting will try out and let you know.

Comment: I am already in the users session on the client side where this query happens then why do I need to use Parse.User.become.